# Laravel 7 - Trait 'Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens' not found

Tags: php, laravel, iframe, token

I am working with iframes and I am trying to compare the user's email with the teacher's email with eloquent. That would be the condition to list only the groups of that teacher, but it gives me this error:

> Trait 'Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens' not found

- This is my function

```
    public function index($id)
        {
             $email = User::select('email')->where('id', $id)->get();
    
            $groups= DB::table('groups')
            ->join('teacher_group', 'grupo_profesor.idGrupo', '=', 'groups.idGrupo')
            ->join('teachers', 'teachers.idTeacher', '=', 'teacher_group.idTeacher')
            ->join('level_group', 'level_group.idGroup', '=', 'groups.idGroup')
            ->join('levels', 'levels.idLevel', '=', 'level_group.idLevel')
            ->join('courses', 'courses.idCourse', '=', 'levels.idCourse')
            ->join('programs', 'programs.idProgram', '=', 'courses.idProgram')
            ->where('teachers.email', '=', $email)
            ->paginate(10);
             
        return view('teacherGroups.index', compact('groups','email'));
        }
```

- The sidebar button

```
<button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action small text-secondary" 
onclick="crearTabAndIframe('TeacherGroups','teacherGroups');
Loadiframe('{{ url('Groups/Teacher/'.auth()->user()->id)}}','ifrmTeacherGroups')">

     <i class="material-icons">list</i> @lang('menu.List')

</button>
```

- This is the index view

```
     @foreach($groups as $group)   
    <tr>
        <td class="small text-center">{{$group->idGroup}}</td>
    
        <td class="small  text-center">{{$group->levelName}} {{$group->courseName}} {{$group->programName}}</td>
    
        <td class="small  text-center">{{$group->teacher_name}}</td>
        
        <td class="small  text-center">
            <div class="row small">
                <div >
                    <!--VIEW-->
                    <button onclick="seeGroup({{$group->idGroup}})" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">
                        <i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i>
                    </button>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

- And with the error it shows me this part of my model

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
    
    {
    
        use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    
     
    
        /**
    
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    
         *
    
         * @var string[]
    
         */
    
        protected $fillable = [
    
            'name',
    
            'email',
    
            'password',
    
        ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This, looks like you need to install sanctum

```
composer require laravel/sanctum
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. Now I have this error: `Trait 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory' not found`. I have a similar function for user profile and I don't get any error. Could it be something else?

Comment: have you try `composer dump-autoload` command ?

Comment: not found meaning that class or trait is not in your project. can you check it in vendor folder with path Laravel > Framework > src > Illuminate > Database > Eloquent > Factories ?

Comment: I have `Factory.php` instead of Factories

Comment: And yes, I already try `composer dump-autoload` but still the same error

Comment: remove all vendor folder. then try to re-install again with composer install

Comment: Oh! I think I have it, I changed my `Use app\Model\User;` to `Use app\User;` and I don't get the error anymore, but my view comes up blank. It only shows the column titles of the table, but no data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I guess SanctumServiceProvider is not automatically registered in your application. To resolve your issue, you should add the service provider manually in config/app.php.

```
'providers' => [
    //...
    Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider::class,
];
```

Comment: I solved that error, I changed my `Use app\Model\User;` to `Use app\User;` and I don't get the error anymore, but my view comes up blank. It only shows the column titles of the table, but no data from the database.

Comment: oh i see that's nice